# Get data-attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I like to take the `data-color` and output it inside the `value` of the hidden input field. This should happen if a radio button gets checked.

How could this be done?

```html
<input type="hidden" id="color" name="color" value=""/>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="" data-color="option1">
<label for="radio1">
option1
</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="" data-color="option2">
<label for="radio1">
option2
</label>
```

Comment: where is the javascript you have written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [HTMLElement dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

In order to select all input type radio having the data-color  attribute:

```
$(':radio').filter((i, e) => {return $(e).data('color')})
```

My snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $(':radio').filter((i, e) => {return $(e).data('color')}).on('change', function(e) {
    $('#color').val(this.dataset.color);
    console.log("$('#color').val('" + this.dataset.color + "')");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="color" name="color" value=""/>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="" data-color="option1">
<label for="radio1">
    option1
</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="" data-color="option2">
<label for="radio1">
    option2
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: I made the `#color` input `text` instead of `hidden` just so you can see things working. I also gave both radio buttons a common class and gave them unique IDs. (All HTML elements on the page should have unique IDs.)

```js
$(function () {
  $('.color-button').change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#color').val($('.color-button:checked').data('color'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="color" name="color" value=""/>


<input type="radio" id="radio1" class="color-button" name="radio" value="" data-color="option1">
<label for="radio1">
option1
</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio2" class="color-button" name="radio" value="" data-color="option2">
<label for="radio2">
option2
</label>
```